# Is there any way to turn on virtualization without using BIOS?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, bios, lenovo-laptop

In my Lenovo G-580 Laptop I've lost the interface to access the  BIOS menus and before lost this interface I've turned off the virtualization from BIOS. so the main problem is there is no way to access the BIOS interface for me and I also want to turn on virtualization.

Is there any way to turn on virtualization using Os and any other tool.

Note: I've tried every possible method to access my BIOS but unfortunately I can not to this so and I want only virtulization on so I need such a method or technique to do without BIOS.

Comment: If the option does not exist to turn on virtualization then there is no way to enable it using the hardware you have.

Comment: @SeanClt - Answer is the same. It must be enabled within the BIOS before Windows will detect its enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound tested the bcdedit on my powered it doesn't work

Comment: How do you "lose the interface to access the BIOS" and wouldn't a laptop (like a desktop can) stop on a cleared settings bios and ask the user what they want to do now?  AKA couldnt you just clear the cmos or pull the battery and force it into asking ?  Different keyboard or something?

Comment: Have you ASKED how to fix your BIOS? You definitely have not tried every possible method.

Comment: As above, "losing" BIOS is really unusual, did you physically damage the BIOS chip? That's the only way I can think of. In that case you could probably take it to the repair shop and have the chip replaced.